# CodeIgniter - Can't load view after loading model

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am exploring codeigniter for quite some time and most of the problem i faced while exploring it already solved by googling it but the problem i am facing right now is kind of weird. So here is the situation. I have a controller which will validate the form and pass all input from the form to the model using array if there is no error after the validation.

I have another function in the same controller which will send out email upon called. So what i wanted to do is validate the form, sent all input using array to model and insert it into the database then send email to the user's email address.

Below is part of the code from signup controller :

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    //load custom config
    $this->config->load('site_config', TRUE);
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('form');

    //retrieve data
    $data['site_title'] = $this->config->item('site_title', 'site_config');
    $data['site_login'] = $this->config->item('site_login', 'site_config');
    $data['site_url'] = $this->config->item('site_url', 'site_config');
    $data['img_folder_path'] = $this->config->item('img_folder_path', 'site_config');

    $this->load->view('view_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('view_signup',$data);
    $this->load->view('view_footer');
}else{
    $this->load->model('Adduserinfointoactivationtable');

    $user_infos = array('first_name'                 =>  $this->input->post('first_name'),
                        'last_name'                  =>  $this->input->post('last_name'),
                        'email'                      =>  $this->input->post('email'),
                        'tel'                        =>  $this->input->post('tel'),
                        'fax'                        =>  $this->input->post('fax'),
                        'add_1'                      =>  $this->input->post('add_1'),
                        'add_2'                      =>  $this->input->post('add_2'),
                        'city'                       =>  $this->input->post('city'),
                        'post_code'                  =>  $this->input->post('post_code'),
                        'state'                      =>  $this->input->post('state'),
                        'password'                   =>  sha1($this->input->post('pass_2')),
                        'activation_code'            =>  sha1(sha1($this->input->post('email').$this->input->post('pass_2'))),
                        );

    $this->Adduserinfointoactivationtable->addUserInfo($user_infos);
    $this->send_mail();
}
```

Here is the model :

```
public function addUserInfo ($user_infos){

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user_Account (email_add, activation_code, fname, lname, tel, fax, add1, add2, city, post_code, state, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($user_infos['email'], $user_infos['activation_code'], $user_infos['first_name'], $user_infos['last_name'], $user_infos['tel'], $user_infos['fax'], $user_infos['add_1'], $user_infos['add_2'], $user_infos['city'], $user_infos['post_code'], $user_infos['state'], $user_infos['password']));

$query->result_array();

}
```

when i place the `$this->send_mail();` right after the else, it works. I did some testing and the email function is working fine. but when i call it this way which is after `$this->Adduserinfointoactivationtable->addUserInfo($user_infos);`, it doesn't send out email. I also noticed no matter what i do after `$this->Adduserinfointoactivationtable->addUserInfo($user_infos);`, for example load a view or echo out something, it doesn't work.

Can someone advice me on this?

Comment: why are you doing     $query->result_array(); ??

Comment: Yeah, too careless because copying code and paste it without double check. Should care more on the model next time because of the data is inserted, i didn't pay much attention to the model. Thanks again for commenting and point it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue might be the fact that, according to the [CodeIgniter documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html), `$this->db->query()` returns a boolean value if an "insert" type query is performed.

This is happening in your case. Because of this, you're probably creating a fatal error by executing `$query->result_array()`.

As a simple fix, you can probably try the following:

```php
if (is_object($query)) {
    return $query->result_array();
} else {
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Hi garbetjie, thanks a bunch. Yeah, it works now. This might be so stupid because i am inserting data and not selecting data... i am going to accept this as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading any view in the else part, are you? Do a redirect to the same function or to a success function page.

Comment: Hi Nil'z. As i said i tried to do the simple thing as just echo after it and doesn't work as well.